Unable to export baked shape keys with animation as .fbx blender 4.0 and 4.2.1
I am attempting to export a .fbx file from blender to unreal that includes a character and their animations.
The problem:
upon export and reimport to blender or unreal the mesh, rig, morph targets/shape keys, and animation, all import successfully. The problem is the shape keys animation is lost. I have tried numerous methods of baking the shape keys before exporting but the baked shape key action is always lost on export.
What I've tried:
over the last week I have tried every tutorial and forum solution I could find including:
blenders built in object/animation/bake action
bake shape keys add on
bake drivers add on
every combination of animation bake on .fbx export including disabling bake animation
What I've learned:
I can copy paste the character, rig, and animation layers to a new project and they still work
I can delete the rig and shape key drivers after baking, and they still work
I can see the baked shape keyframes in the dope sheet/shape key editor and graph editor and NLA strip before pushing down
whenever I reimport, the shape keyframes all disappear completely.
The export setting Force start/end keying forces the action/NLA layer to remain upon import, but all the frames are still lost other than the added start and end frames.



Shape keys will not export if the export settings modify your mesh in any way. In my case, I had the Triangulate Mesh option enabled during export because I work with quads and needed the mesh triangulated for import into a game engine. I unchecked the Triangulate option and instead triangulated the mesh in Blender manually using Edit Mode > Ctrl+T before exporting. That solved the problem.
